# What test is appropriate?

Tags: anova, variance, mean, spss, dataset

can I do welch one way anova to compare mean between the following three groups
Group 1 has 83 observations
Group 2 has 15 observations
Group 3 has only 2 observations

And in group 3 the variance is 0 so the welch test cannot be performed, how should I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: I've voted to close this question because the OP posted the [same question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567745/which-test-should-be-performed-if-variance-is-0) earlier today.

Comment: You can vote against the other question too